# Adding sequence number in rtf template in fusion

Tags: oracle, templates, rtf, bi-publisher, fusion

I am trying to add sequence number in rtf template. I have added one condition in rtf of not displaying the row whose job is consultant. So the sequence number is not generated in correct sequence.
Below is the data:
S No.  Name    Job
1     Abhay    Developer
2     Anant    Consultant
3     Anushka  Manager

Output displayed:
S No.  Name    Job
1     Abhay    Developer
3     Anushka  Manager

I have used the following xml:
<xsl:value-of select=”position()”/>

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variable on the RTF.

**Set Variable**

```
<?xdoxslt:set_variable($_XDOCTX, ‘v_position’, 0)?>
```

**Add 1 to variable**

```
<?xdoxslt:set_variable($_XDOCTX, 'v_position',xdoxslt:get_variable($_XDOCTX,'v_position')+1)?>
```

**Display variable**

```
<?xdoxslt:get_variable($_XDOCTX,'v_position')?>
```

Comment: Please upvote the answer. Thanks!